# TListView with CheckBoxes and SubItemImages

Tags: delphi, listview

Using the standard TListView component (`ViewStyle = vsReport`), I have attached a TImageList and have successfully added images to both the first column (`Item.ImageIndex := 0`) and to the subsequent columns (`Items[0].SubItemImages[1] := 1`).

If I then set the CheckBoxes property to True, the images on SubItems disappear. The main image remains (the one set by `Item.ImageIndex`) but the SubItems lose their images.

I have also noticed that the `OnGetSubItemImage` event doesn't fire when `CheckBoxes = True`

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot have both of them with the standard control since windows itself uses images for those 'checkboxes', hence you will have to owner draw each list item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is a very old bug, when you activate the CheckBoxes property would disable the LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES and
LVS_EX_INFOTIP styles on the TListView control.

you can use this workaround for fix this bug.

**1)** Disable the checkbox property in the listview

**2)** Put this code (Tested in Delphi 7 and windows 7) in your form .

```
const
  LVM_FIRST =$1000;
  LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES         = $00000002;
  LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE = LVM_FIRST + 54;
  LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE = LVM_FIRST + 55;


function ListView_GetExtendedListViewStyle(LVWnd: HWnd): DWORD;
begin
  Result := SendMessage(LVWnd, LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, 0);
end;

function ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(LVWnd: HWnd; ExStyle: LPARAM): DWORD;
begin
  Result := SendMessage(LVWnd, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, ExStyle);
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
ListView1.Checkboxes:=True;//Activate the checkbox in the listview
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(ListView1.Handle,ListView_GetExtendedListViewStyle(ListView1.Handle) OR LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES); //Activate the LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES style.
end;
```

**3)** and the final result is

[image]

Comment: hw did u add the image to this after the style was applied?

Answer (score 0):

Well this doesn't help particularly, but the TMS TAdvListView component handles it with its `SubImages` property. Set this to True and I can have Checkboxes and sub item images. I'm sure there's a lot of good work going on behind the scenes. At least this moves me forward.